# I have eclipse luna, how do I add eclipse indigo?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded the [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/marsr), unzipped and got it created a new folder in my C drive. Everything worked fine. Now I want to code in Javascript. So I downloaded the [Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/indigosr2). Now I need to know how to add it to my already existing IDE. Thanks.

Comment: Indigo is a much older release of Eclipse - you do not use it with Luna.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh, they are versions. Then how do I get all the features of Indo, integrated into Luna.

Comment: if you are not coding for Java, you can use Visual Studio community for JavaScript development has everything you need

Comment: Luna has all the features of Indigo (and more) you can install them through 'Help > Install New Software' (or some via the Marketplace).

Comment: Unpack your two Eclipse versions to separate directories.  Code your Java and your Javascript in separate workspaces.  Never try and combine Eclipses.  It's just like crossing the streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of downloading it again you can directly add the plugin for javascript from eclipse market place 
Goto help-->> Eclipse Marketplace and then search for javascript plugin and install it and it will be added to your IDE.

Comment: yes but the other ide has "Tools for JavaScript developers creating Web applications, including a JavaScript IDE, tools for JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and XML.", I can't get all of that in one single package on the marketplace. I already downloaded it by the way, how do I add it, I also want to be able to code in HTMl.

Comment: Actually you can not add multiple IDE all together you need to download plugins to get the functionality.